# Finding an alternative nicer way to evaluate the summation

Tags: sequences-and-series

> If in a series $t_n=\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}$ then find the value of
> $$\sum_{n=0}^{10}t_n$$

I can easily do this question by finding the fractions but that will be a too tiresome task.

Is there any better way of evaluating this$?$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}=\frac1{(n+1)!}-\frac1{(n+2)!}$

Comment: Giving some [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) is helpful, not only to those writing answers, but also to you, giving you some possible avenues of attack. For example, was this question given in a section studying [telescoping series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)?